# Sagepay test - "The Vendor configuration is missing or invalid" while using Simulator with Form Kit

Tags: asp.net, configuration, simulator, opayo

I get this error while trying to test the latest version (3.0) of Sagepay with the the form kit. But when yo login to Sagepay simulator, it will ask you to change the sagepay.api.formPaymentUrl.TEST key in the web.config file to https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPFormGateway.asp. But then you get this error "The **VPSProtocol** field you supplied contains invalid data. It should contain the value **2.23**". So I changed sagepay.api.protocolVersion key in web config to 2.23. After doing this I shopping cart fails on ExtraInformation.aspx page and there is no button to proceed further. After spending 2 days on Google trying to find a solution I finally gave up and followed a different approach. I tried debugging the code.

Answer (score 1):

In web.config file, have the following:

```
sagepay.kit.basketxml.disable = true
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sagepay Simulator does not support v3.0 you need a proper test account.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It does answer the question, the OP is trying to test v 3.0 protocol on a simulator that doesn't support it, so it won't work no matter what he does!